# Insert into new table and a join table at the same time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table called **buyers** and a table called **sellers** and I want to introduce a table called **contacts** that holds contact details for both buyers and sellers.

Focusing on the buyers first, I want a join table **buyers_contacts** to join buyers to contacts.

I want to initially fill the contacts table with one entry for each buyer. Then for each contact, I want to create a row in buyers_contacts.

How should I do this?

So far I have come up with this query (with incorrect syntax).

```
with buyer as (
    select name, id from buyers
)
, new_contact as (
    insert into contacts (name) select name from buyer
    returning id as contact_id, buyer.id as buyer_id
)
insert into buyers_contacts (buyer_id, contact_id) values 
(new_contact.buyer_id, new_contact.contact_id);
```

I have thought about doing this update in two stage, first creating a contact for each buyer, and and then inserting into the buyers_contacts table but I cannot rely on the buyers to have unique names.

I feel like this should be a solved problem but, there are no examples that seem to fit this situation.

Postgres is the database I am using.

Comment: What does this mean "I cannot rely on the buyers to have unique names"?  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Why not just make `contacts` a view so you don't have to maintain data in multiple locations? Aside from the initial data load, updates to either source table will be an on-going sync issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is some sequence behind the scenes that generates the contact Id when to create a new record:

```
create sequence contact_id;
```

I think all you have to do to add the buyers is this:

```
insert into contacts (contact_id, buyer_id)
select
  nextval ('contact_id'), b.id
from buyer b
where not exists (
  select null
  from contacts c
  where c.buyer_id = b.id
)
```

This will create new contact records at any time for only the buyers who have not already been added to the table.

You can also just rely on the default value:

```
insert into contacts (buyer_id)
select
  b.id
from buyer b
where not exists (
  select null
  from contacts c
  where c.buyer_id = b.id
)
```